# Unable to send from Postfix as smart host to port 465 at ISP mail server

Tags: postfix, email-server

Till now i was thinking that i was using port 465 instead of port 25 of my ISP mail server, where my smart host is connected, but after doing some tests i notice that i was using port 25.

In my main.cf i had before:

```
relayhost = [mail.X.pt]:25
smtp_fallback_relay = [cpanel.ideiasfrescas.pt]:465
```

whit,

```
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/sasl/passwd
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/relayhost/maps
```

where i have for each user a personalised connection with port at maps file for SMTP Auth at my ISP mail server,

```
teste@X.pt [cpanel.ideiasfrescas.pt]:465
```

But when i changed at relayhost to use port 465 at cpanel.ideiasfrescas.pt, i notice that i was using port 25 and not those ports and server from maps file. I was no longer capable to send mails to my ISP mail server, resulting in this warning at mailq:

```
(lost connection with cpanel.ideiasfrescas.pt[] while receiving the initial server greeting)
```

But this connection at port 465 in my ISP mail server is working fine, at least i can telnet.

So my question is why i am not capable to send to port 465 and its not supposed to use those connections and ports for each user? or because i am having this issue with 465 it uses by default relayhost?

Comment: does your from address match the account

Comment: I didnt understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use 587 (SMTP submission port) which also supports tls, both of these usually expect authentication unless your dynamic ip is wishlisted

Comment: My ISP didnt had given that port to connect but after scanning it i discover that that port is openned but i receive the same message at mailq =/

Comment: must be an issue with your sasl_auth

Comment: Jacob, i have changed all my user SMTP auths to SMTP STARTTLS as well as main.cf relayhost and it is working! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe mark as answered? @SipriusPT

Comment: Sorry Jacob! Done =)

Comment: also good info, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587  Specifically the fact that 465 was deprecated in favor of 587

Comment: I have read that thread about those two but my remote mail server didnt post port 587 for SMTP at cpanel, i didnt knew about that port being openned thats why i have telnet it to see. Thanks one more time for the help =)

Comment: cpanel uses postfix, so you'd be best looking at postfix docs and  it cpanel specifically...understand the workings not the suite